# Dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu on HP ENVY Ultrabook 6t-1100

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uefi, windows-8

I plan to buy [HP ENVY Ultrabook 6t-1100](http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/Laptops/HP-ENVY/B6D94AV?HP-ENVY-Ultrabook-6t-1100) which comes with Windows 8, 32GB SSD and 500GB Hard drive. I however want to Dual boot it with Ubuntu. Any issues? Furthermore, would it be possible to install Ubuntu on SSD and Windows 8 on the standard Hard drive? Is it possible to disable UEFI from BIOS on this system?

Answer (score 1):

- It's not possible to disable UEFI, since UEFI is the type of firmware you've got. That said, it *is* possible to boot most UEFI-based PCs in BIOS/legacy mode rather than in EFI mode. Doing so would require either re-installing Windows or reconfiguring it to boot in BIOS mode rather than in EFI mode. Overall, that's probably not the best way to go.
- Ubuntu 12.10 ships with EFI support. It also supposedly ships with support for booting with Secure Boot active. (Any PC with a Windows 8 logo must ship with Secure Boot active.) That said, I've never tried it, so I don't know how well it works in practice. If necessary, you should be able to disable Secure Boot, too.
- In theory, you should be able to install Ubuntu on the SSD and Windows 8 on the spinning disk.

You may want to check out [my Web page on EFI boot loaders for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) It's not really an EFI primer, but it does have some basic information on it, and on options for how to boot Linux on an EFI-based computer.

Comment: What about the practical steps on your point 3?

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems installing Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8 but this tutorial helped me a lot. Maybe it will help you:

[Dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 on UEFI hardware](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/)

Comment: So you successfully have dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu? Your notebook or PC specs?

Comment: Yes, I have dual boot on my system. My laptop is an HP Pavilion dv5 not UEFI hardware but this was the only way I was able to install Ubuntu and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ubuntu12.10 has some issues with UEFI but running Boot-Repair after installing Ubuntu solves them. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
2. Computers sold with Windows8 all have SecureBoot, which may cause problems (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot ), so better buying a computer without preinstalled Win8.
3. To avoid compatibility problems, best is buying a computer with preinstalled Ubuntu or without OS. Nowdays, there are cheap ones, eg at ubuntu-fr we generally recommend Clevo laptop, they are all compatible with Ubuntu12.04/12.10, and there are good ones for 350$. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed